# Give a geometric description of the following set of points

Tags: calculus, 3d

Give a geometric description of the following set of points:

$x^2 +y^2 + z^2-8x+14y-18z>/= 65 $

So I completed the square and got the set to read: 
$(x-4)^2+(y+7)^2+(z-9)^2>/= 211 $

However the answer in the book says this is the set of all points outside of a ball with center (-4,7,-9) and radius of radical 211. How do you know this is the set of points outside of a ball? What would be different if this was these the set of all points within a ball?

Comment: \geq gives $\geq$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$(x-4)^2+(y+7)^2+(z-9)^2 > 211 $$

Take the square root of both sides.

$$\sqrt{(x-4)^2+(y+7)^2+(z-9)^2} > \sqrt{211} $$

You will recognize the left side as a Euclidian distance. Thus, this expression describes a set of points $(x,y,z)$ that are more than $\sqrt{211}$ in Euclidian distance away from the point $(4,-7,9)$.

A ball is a set of points which are all the same distance away from some point. For instance,

$$\sqrt{(x-4)^2+(y+7)^2+(z-9)^2} = \sqrt{211} $$

is set of points all $\sqrt{211}$ distance away from $(4,-7,9)$. If you wanted all the points inside of this ball, you'd just reverse the inequality:

$$\sqrt{(x-4)^2+(y+7)^2+(z-9)^2} < \sqrt{211} $$

Comment: how can you tell that the points are not the same distance away from some point?

Comment: Any particular point $(x,y,z)$ in the original set might be the same distance from some other point. Any one particular point can lie on many different balls or outside of many different balls. That's not a problem. While the points in the original set might be more than $\sqrt{221}$ away from other points, here we are only concerned with whether they are more than this distance from one particular point.

Comment: can you show me the calculation done? Sorry, I'm still confused. Would I add 4^2 and 7^2 and 9^2 and compare that number to 211?

Comment: Which calculation are you trying to do exactly? Check to see if some point is in the first set?

Comment: If so, calculate $(x-4)^2+(y+7)^2+(z-9)^2$ and compare to $211$

Comment: wouldn't that be $ x^2-8x+16+y^2+14y+49+z^2-18z+81 $

Comment: so this is less than 211...?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35111/discussion-between-commonerg-and-lil).